# How to draw a widget in QItemDelegate's paint method

Tags: ubuntu, delegates, qt4

[Discussed in year 2007](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8660-Drawing-a-widget-in-QItemDelegate-s-paint-method) but not clearly answered to me. Is it possible to show `QWidget` in `paint` function in `QAbstractItemDelegate`?

---

Below are what I want to achieve. In the hope this might help.

I have data items implemented as `QStandardItem` and I want to show on 2 different views. On 1 view (say View-A) I just display static value so I don't even need delegation. But on another one (View-B), before even users start editing I want to display editor widget that each item has as its member. View-A and View-B have the same number of elements (items) shown in different format. View-B shows elements in a vertical list and because the number of items can become over 100, View-B usually shows vertical scrollbar.

Clicking on any item on View-A will highlight the corresponding item on View-B (I'm thinking to achieve this by `QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex` or else, not sure since I haven't tested yet but having this functionality is one of the reasons that I stick to trying either MVC or any ItemWidget classes).